# Add tags to Safe HTML

Tags: xss, discussion

When I select "Allow only safe HTML" for EE's discussion forum it correctly allows tags for links, images, bold etc but it doesn't seem to allow `<ol>` or `<li>`. Is there any way to add these to the list of safe HTML tags for EE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Word of Warning**
First let me warn you the below technique involved modifying core files, and is not recommended. If you update EE you may overwrite these chnages!

What you want to do is add tags to the EE Typography class. `/system/expressionengine/libraries/EE_Typeography.php`.

To add UL, OL and LI open this file, look to lines 143 to 165 (ish), you will see sometihng like this :

```
    /** -------------------------------------
    /**  Allowed tags
    /** -------------------------------------*/

    // Note: The decoding array is associative, allowing more precise mapping

    $this->safe_encode = array('b', 'i', 'em', 'del', 'ins', 'strong', 'pre', 'code', 'blockquote');

    $this->safe_decode = array(
        'b'             => 'b',
        'i'             => 'i',
        'em'            => 'em',
        'del'           => 'del',
        'ins'           => 'ins',
        'strong'        => 'strong',
        'pre'           => 'pre',
        'code'          => 'code',
        'blockquote'    => 'blockquote',
        'quote'         => 'blockquote',
        'QUOTE'         => 'blockquote'
    );
```

To allow the BB style version, add the tags to the `safe_decode` array, to allow the html version to be encoded as well add them to the `safe_encode` array. So to allow both BB and HTML OL's and UL's :

```
    /** -------------------------------------
    /**  Allowed tags
    /** -------------------------------------*/

    // Note: The decoding array is associative, allowing more precise mapping

    $this->safe_encode = array('b', 'i', 'em', 'del', 'ins', 'strong', 'pre', 'code', 'blockquote', 'ol', 'ul', 'li');

    $this->safe_decode = array(
        'b'             => 'b',
        'i'             => 'i',
        'em'            => 'em',
        'del'           => 'del',
        'ins'           => 'ins',
        'strong'        => 'strong',
        'pre'           => 'pre',
        'code'          => 'code',
        'blockquote'    => 'blockquote',
        'quote'         => 'blockquote',
        'QUOTE'         => 'blockquote',
        'ol'            => 'ol',
        'ul'            => 'ul',
        'li'            => 'li'
    );
```

Enjoy :) Mark as answer if you accept :D

Comment: Happy to help :)